# Custom UI layouts for Cognito login sdk AWS

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

Are there any sample projects or any sample code that helps with the creation of custom sign up/sign in layouts for AWS Cognito?  I have gone through all of the given Git samples from AWS but I am not able to figure out much about this. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried/found/figured out so far?

Comment: Does "all the given git samples of aws" include these?  https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples  There are two Cognito demo projects in there, complete with code and resources including layouts.